# Oracle: Get list of functions for user

Tags: oracle

How do I get a list of all the functions for a particular user?

EDIT for question clarification:

When (as USER1) I run

```
select * from all_objects
where owner = 'USER2'
and object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

it doesn't return all the functions that I know USER2 owns.  I suspect that it is only returning those functions that USER1 is allowed to view/execute.

Is that suspicion correct?

Also, if that is true, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What does "functions *for* a particular user" mean?  Functions owned by?  Usable by?

Comment: Can you fix the title to actually reflect what you're actually asking?  Also, there's a complete edit history; you don't need to write "EDIT".  Just fix your question to be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your suspicion is correct.  The ALL_OBJECTS view will only list those items that the current user has access to.

If you can log in as USER2, then you can query USER_OBJECTS as that user to see all objects owned by that user.

If you can log in as SYSTEM, then you would have access to all objects regardless of owner, so the list provided by ALL_OBJECTS (or DBA_OBJECTS) would be complete.

If you can't log in as a user that has access to all of USER2's objects, then you can't list all of USER2's objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a list of functions the belong to a particular user then:

```
select object_name
from   all_objects
where  owner = 'WHOEVER'
and    object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

This will return only stand-alone functions, not procedures or function in packages, that belong to the schema 'WHOEVER'.

To obtain a list of **all** functions that the current user can access:

```
select object_name
from   all_objects
where  object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

Comment: I ran this.  A few issues: first off, should be `object_type`.  Moreover, this didn't seem to list all of them.  Will this only list those functions that have execute granted to the user I'm using for the select?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my SQL (I should have tested it before posting!)  This lists only functions that belong to the schema 'WHOEVER'.  To see all functions available to the user from any schema, omit the "owner = 'WHOEVER'" predicate.

Comment: Hmm.  My previous comment wasn't very clear.  I've edited more details into the question.  Thanks for you help on this...

Answer (score 0):

select * from dba_objects
where owner = 'USER2'
and object_type = 'FUNCTION';